# Flex Instantiated Object - wait for creationComplete

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, instantiation, wait

I have a simple component I created which I instantiate in my main program like so:

```
newMessage = new MessageDetail();
newMessage.body.text = "Hello World";
```

I receive the error "*Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference*" on the second line because newMessage was not fully created prior to hitting the second line of code trying to set my "body" textarea's text. I know I can build a "creationComplete" event handler, but isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't access sub-components at all.

Instead make regular old properties on your component.  Have the component bind those values to visual components.

For example:

MyComponent.MXML:

```
<mxml blah blah blah>

<script>
  [Bindable] public var bodyText;
</scipt>


<mx:TextArea text="{bodyText}" />
</mxml>
```

In your code:

```
myComponent = new MyComponent()
myComponent.bodyText = "Hello World!";
```

In general, I believe sub-components being public by default was a huge mistake in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to create create all children in your component by overriding method createChildren(). It will make sure all children are instantiated. More [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) and [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_3.html)

```
    public class MessageDetail() 
    {

        // ...
        private var body:TextArea;
        // ...

        protected override function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            body = new TextArea();
            addChild(body);
        }
```

EDIT:

```
newMessage = new MessageDetail();
addChild(newMessage); // During this step all children will to be initialized
newMessage.body.text = "Hello World";
```

Thanks to Michael Brewer-Davis for comment

Comment: This is true but not relevant--the createChildren() method is fine here.  But it isn't called until initialize(), i.e., when the object is added to the display list.

Comment: So using this method theres no way I can really use the design view to see what its going to look like? My MessageDetail component has about 8 child components. It would be nice if there was a wait function to wait for a specified object to load.

Comment: My point was that the code in your edit, using addChild(), would have worked even without a custom createChildren() method.